# Open iOS Safari Shared links via javascript or html

Tags: ios7

I have a requirement to open the "Shared Links" component in Safari (iOS 7+) via clicking a button in a html page. I can open the print dialog via window.print() but don't know how to open the sharing popup. May be this is not allowed by Apple due to security concerns.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this wasn't possible using a default webview.